# Continuing after an exception

Tags: python

```
class Bool():

    def __init__(self, mode):
        self._mode = mode

    def switch(self):  
        if self._mode is False:
            raise Exception
        self._mode = False

class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self._lst = [False, True, False, True]

    def __str__(self):
        return "list: " + str(self._lst)

    def normal(self):
        for index, element in enumerate(self._lst):
            try:
                Bool(element).switch()
            except Exception:
                continue
```

The problem with my code is that the method normal doesn't appear to work. What it's supposed to do is take the lst and turn all the True's to False's by calling the switch method from another class. And if the element is False, instead of raising any exception it should just skip it and move on to the next element.

```
t1 = Test()
print(t1)
list: [False, True, False, True]
t1.normal()
print(t1)
list: [False, True, False, True]
```

however it should actually be:

```
t1 = Test()
print(t1)
list: [False, True, False, True]
t1.normal()
print(t1)
list: [False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: code `Bool(element).switch()` does not affect the value of `self._lst` in `class Test`

Comment: So the function should just turn all elements to `False`? If so: `self._lst = [False]*len(self._lst)`

Comment: Please do not write comparisons like `is False`. You are creating a way for the code to fail, with no benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the values in `_lst`. Also, since `switch()` method doesn't return anything, you should store the instance of `Bool`, call its `switch()` method and then assign it to the respective element in `_lst`

```
def normal(self):
    for index, element in enumerate(self._lst):
        try:
            b = Bool(element)  # Store instance
            b.switch()
            self._lst[index] = b._mode  # Change the respective element
        except Exception as e:
            print e  # Just for debug
```